# Tracking visitors to help support

Tags: php

I am looking to find a way to gain information about how my visitors are going through my website and if they come across any errors, the errors are known along with the information about the visitor, so when they email for support I will have this information available. I don't want to be thought of spying on the visitor, but our audience does not provide much details about the problems they encounter which makes it difficult at times to track down the incident. Does anyone have suggestions on php programs that might be available, or simply php code that would handle this? Any suggestions would be appreciated to help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly suggest looking at: http://reinvigorate.net/ for tracking how users are using your site (It has heatmaps to show where users are clicking - and you can track visitors on an individual basis). - Whilst it doesn't integrate with your application (in that you can't tie this information to their account) - it shouldnt be two hard to simply load up reinvigorate and simply check what happened (if you have their username / ip).

Comment: Thank you, I have started using this program and it is giving me some very valuable insight, especially the snoop tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could log it into your Mysql Database if you have one, setup an tracking script to recieve any ip that logs in, then use "or die()" on your mysql but make it save into a variable then log that also into the database
       
  db: id(A.I, primary),ip Varchar(12),is_checked DEFAULT 0, error(200),date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
then check if you have a error,
    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_errors Where, checked=0");
     while($row = mysql_num_rows($query)){
     echo $row['id'].$row['error'].$row['date'];
}